# Windows Azure Webservices custom Authentication

Tags: web-services, authentication, azure

Greetings fellow Stackoverflowiens,

I have web services and a database setup in Windows Azure and I am using the javascript backend for the web services as this gives me basic CRUD calls without having to write the API. I also have a user table for all users that can login on the app with a field for username and password, I am trying to authenticate the user based on this table without writing the entire API. I can't just do a GET call to see if the user has entered a valid username and password as this would not be secure. And I can't use the Facebook, Twitter or other 3rd party authentication services as the requirement is to use a database of users.

Is there anyway of implementing a custom authentication into Azure without writing the entire API? Or is there another way of doing this that I am not aware of?

Any help that can be provided would be fantastic

Comment: What is your web service? Asp.Net Web API or WCF?